# Disabling Gzip Input Decompression in AWS Elastic Map Reduce

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, compression, amazon-emr

I'm running a MapReduce task on Gzipped .arc files. Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999734/hadoop-converting-r-n-to-n-and-breaking-arc-format), I'm having difficulties as the Gzip decompression is running automatically (since files have a .gz extension), but it is causing issues on newline/carriage-return being rendered as just newline as per Unix file encoding. This makes the input completely unreadable since it depends on specific character counts embedded in the file. I am trying to disable the Gzip decompression so I can do it instead in my mapper, correctly. I have tried:

```
 -jobconf stream.recordreader.compression=none
```

But that doesn't seem to affect the compression. Is there any way I can prevent Gzip decompression on my input?

Thanks, -Geoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've identified the potential problem, and a work around on the question you've referenced:

- [hadoop converting \r\n to \n and breaking ARC format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999734/hadoop-converting-r-n-to-n-and-breaking-arc-format)

Basically its a problem in PipeMapper.java, which you can easily amend