# org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: hadoop, emr, snappy

I have a 90MB snappy compressed file that I am attempting to use as input to Hadoop 2.2.0 on AMI 3.0.4 in AWS EMR.

Immediately upon attempting to read the file my record reader gets the following exception:

```
2014-05-06 14:25:34,210 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BlockDecompressorStream.getCompressedData(BlockDecompressorStream.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BlockDecompressorStream.decompress(BlockDecompressorStream.java:98)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:365)
...
```

I'm running on an m1.xlarge in AWS using the default memory and io.sort.mb.  If we decompress the file and use that as input instead everything goes fine.  Trouble is we have a very large number of compressed files and don't want to go around decompressing everything.

I'm not sure if we're missing a configuration setting or a wiring in our code of some sort.  Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The file is a .sz file and was created with snzip.  I do have a custom code definition for .sz files (io.compression.codecs).

Comment: If I change the file extension from .sz to .unknown, I am able to read the entire file and the map job completes successfully.  I believe this question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558315/load-snappy-compressed-files-into-elastic-mapreduce

Answer (score 2):

As per the log you have provided , it seems size of decompressed block is more than your available heap size.
 I don't know about m1.large instance specifications on EMR, however here are some of the things you can try to ward off this error.
 Usually error running child means , the **child that yarn spawned can't find enough heap space to continue its MR job**.
 Options to try :
 1) Increase `mapred.java.child.opts` size. It is the default size that child gets as its separate JVM process. By default, its 200mb , which is small for any reasonable data analysis. Change the parameters `-XmxNu`( max heapsize of N in u units) and `-XmsNu` (initial heap size of N in units of  u ). Try for 1Gb i.e. -Xmx1g and see the effect and if it succeeds then go smaller
 2) set up `mapred.child.ulimit` to 1.5 or 2 times the size of max heap size as set previously. It sets the amount of virtual memory for for a process.
 3) reduce `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` and `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` to set max no of parallel mappers and reducers running at a time.
4) `io.sort.mb` - which you have already tried. try it to `0.25*mapred.child.java.opts < io.sort.mb < 0.5*mapred.child.java.opts` .
 And at last, its a trial and error method, so try and see which one sticks.

Comment: I set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx2g which is the maximum available, but still received the same exception.  (Note I am on 2.2.0 so mapreduce.map.java.opts is the new equivalent to mapred.java.child.opts.)Then I added to this setting the mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=1 and received the same error again.  Lastly I added mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb=819, and received the same error.  I did not set ulimit because there was a message in my output "The variable mapred.child.ulimit is no longer used."

Comment: @SarahHaskins  Ok..so the problem was with how EMR handles snappy compressed data. Anyway good to know.. and all parameters I wrote were tested on hadoop-1.2.x.