# how to write a streaming mapreduce job for warc files in python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, warc

I am trying to write a mapreduce job for warc files using [WARC library](http://warc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) of python. 
Following code is working for me but i need this code for hadoop mapreduce jobs.

```
import warc
f = warc.open("test.warc.gz")
for record in f:
    print record['WARC-Target-URI'], record['Content-Length']
```

I want this code to read streaming input from warc files i.e.

```
zcat test.warc.gz | warc_reader.py
```

Kindly tell me how can i modify this code for streaming inputs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`warc.open()` is a shorthand for `warc.WARCFile()`, and `warc.WARCFile()` can receive a `fileobj` argument, where `sys.stdin` is exactly a file object. So what you need to do is something simply like this:

```
import sys
import warc

f = warc.open(fileobj=sys.stdin)
for record in f:
    print record['WARC-Target-URI'], record['Content-Length']
```

But things are a little bit difficult under hadoop streaming when your input file is `.gz`, as hadoop will replace all `\r\n` in WARC file into `\n`, which will break the WARC format(refer to this question: [hadoop converting \r\n to \n and breaking ARC format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999734/hadoop-converting-r-n-to-n-and-breaking-arc-format)). As the `warc` package use a regular expression `"WARC/(\d+.\d+)\r\n"` to match headers(matching exactly `\r\n`), you will probably get this error:

```
IOError: Bad version line: 'WARC/1.0\n'
```

So you will either modify your `PipeMapper.java` file as it is recommended in the referred question, or write your own parsing script, which parses the WARC file line by line.

BTW, simply modifying the `warc.py` to use `\n` instead of `\r\n` in matching headers won't work, because it reads content exactly as the length of `Content-Length`, and expecting two empty lines after that. Therefore what hadoop does will definitely make the length of the content mismatches the attribute `Content-Length` therefore cause another error like:

```
IOError: Expected '\n', found 'abc\n'
```